# python how to work with project skeleton

Tags: python, module, directory, project, bin

I'm having troubles with working with a 'project skeleton' in Python. I have to make a module in this project skeleton file and make it work. Then, I have to make a file that I'm able to run. After a lot of searching, I still can't make it work. This is what the project file looks like:

```
setup.py
NAME/
    __init__.py
bin/
docs/
tests/
    NAME_tests.py
    __init__.py
```

'NAME' is the name of the project. I've got a few simple questions: how am I able to make a working module and a runnable script with this project setup? Where do I put the code/module, how do I run it in Terminal?

Thanks in advance!
Felix

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking here. Are you asking how to create a Python script that uses the `NAME` module? You have the right directory setup, it looks like.

Comment: Hi Christian, Yes I want to make a script that uses the NAME module. I'm wondering in which file I should put the code for the module and in which file I should put the code that I want to run.